# Is there a hangul syllable frequency list? (or most common every day hangul syllables?)

Tags: hangul

I want to create a hangul font but as I'm not going to do the full unicode block in one shot *(or even at all)* so I figured I could start with the most common/used syllables and release incremental versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these help [the search keyword: “`한글 빈도`” (“*Hangul frequency*”).]:

- **“[Hangul syllable frequency](http://nlp.kookmin.ac.kr/data/syldown.html)”**
- “[Getting Hangul letter frequency and keyboard heatmap from Twitter tweets](https://story.pxd.co.kr/958)”
- “*[Frequencies of Korean Syllables and the Distribution of Syllables of PB Word List](https://www.kjorl.org/upload/pdf/0012003141.pdf)*”
- http://munjanet.net/display/home.php?mode=kosoboard_view&szTblName=fontmunja&id=399
- “*[Research on the Korean word frequency](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/reportData/reportDataView.do?mn_id=207&report_seq=303)*”
- “*[Research on the Korean word frequency #2](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/reportData/reportDataView.do?mn_id=45&report_seq=1)*”
- “*[Phoneme and Syllable Frequencies Based on the Analysis of Entries in the Korean Dictionary](https://www.e-csd.org/upload/10039837.pdf)*”

Comment: Great references, thank you!